# Array Handling in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

Is it possible  to select multiple values dynamically using Excel Macros.What i meant by dynamically is the number of values to be selected should be entered by the User.
My code is

```
monthList = monthList & Chr$(34) & "[Time].[Month].&[" _
& Range("Table_Months").Rows(i).Columns(2).Value & "]" & Chr$(34) & ","
Next i
c_mnth = Left(monthList, Len(monthList) - 2)
c_mnth = Right(c_mnth, Len(c_mnth) - 1)
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[Time].[Month].[Month]"). _
VisibleItemsList = Array(c_mnth)
```

By this code I couldn't make it,because at last variable c_mnth consist of all my required field as single string which has to be individual string to execute the code.

Comment: it would be better if you populate it as `array` in the loop.

Comment: Actually i tried populate using Array and i got struck                 For i = 1 To 4                                             monthList(i - 1) = "[Time].[Month].&[" _
& Range("Table_Months").Rows(i).Columns(2).Value & "]"
Next i                        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[Time].[Month].[Month]"). _
VisibleItemsList = monthList()   now my problem is how to provide all the value that is in array(monthList).If i put m..t(3) it will only give 4th element of the array but i need all in that array.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying? (UNTESTED)

```
Dim MyAr

'
'~~> Rest of your code
'

c_mnth = Left(monthList, Len(monthList) - 2)
c_mnth = Right(c_mnth, Len(c_mnth) - 1)

MyAr = Split(c_mnth, ",")

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[Time].[Month].[Month]"). _
VisibleItemsList = Array(MyAr)
```